# How do i append copy on all my files inside a file directory in SuSE 12.5

Tags: copy, append, mv

I am planning to add copy at the end of all my files as part of file-based migration and then will be removing that copy after migration. I would like to know if there is any command that will help me to append "copy" at the end of all my files and at the same time need to remove that copy after my migration.

Eg:
file1.txt >> file1.txt.copy >>file1.txt (after migration to a different location)

Comment: I actually have approximately 100 files that i need to append copy at the end of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> append "copy" at the end of all my files

```
for f in *; do mv -n "$f" "$f.copy"; done
```

> remove that copy

```
for f in *.copy; do mv -n "$f" "${f:0:-5}"; done
```